# Uncaught URIError: URI malformed - jquery UI tabs on Windows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, uri

I'm using jquery UI tabs in a local Windows development environment. I'm testing with their [demo code](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#default)

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. </p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
    <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede ve</p>

  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that I'm getting a "Uncaught URIError: URI malformed" on this function:

```
function isLocal( anchor ) {
    return anchor.hash.length > 1 &&
        decodeURIComponent( anchor.href.replace( rhash, "" ) ) ===
Uncaught URIError: URI malformed
            decodeURIComponent( location.href.replace( rhash, "" ) );
}
```

I suspect this is due to the URI on windows environment that looks like this:

```
file:///C:/Work/my%20project/yadda%20ac%E7%F5es%20yadda/submenu.html#tabs-1
```

How can I have it working on local Windows, since my clients will want to see it working there before going live? I've tested and I know this is being caused by the encoding of the special characters on the uri (like on the word "acções"). **Is there a way to have it working even with special characters**?

I know I can fix this simply by removing these characters and renaming the file/folder, but I'd like to have a solution that is more client proof in case they decide to rename the folders again (and everything just goes CABOOM on their faces).

Comment: Is your code pure HTML/JavaScript? No server side code? Could you just run a small web server on the demo machine to avoid the problem with file:// URLs?

Comment: This is a bug http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/9518 present for **non-UTF8 URLs**. Anyone knows the workaround for non-UTF8 websites?

Comment: I investigated this issue a bit and it leads to different question - **[how these non UTF-8 characters got to the URIs and should they be there or not?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19702662/684229)**. Please see the included testcase.

Comment: I pasted the demo code into notepad and saved it as test1.html on my desk top double clicked it and it works perfectly.

Comment: @danny117, which demo code you speak about? Please post a clear answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a bug in jquery - http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/9518 - present for non-UTF8 URLs. I had the same problem and solved it. As I couldn't change the encoding of my page to UTF-8, I finally patched my jqueryui and used Rainer Plumer's solution as a workaround, but I had to use it twice because I have some URI parameters which contain encoded URIs. So my solution was

```
decodeURIComponent( unescape( unescape(s)) )
```

More generally, there should probably be repeat-until loop, unescaping until you keep getting the same result. This workaround is not a clean solution for sure. The clean solution is asked here:

[Submit form with get method in non UTF-8 encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19702662/684229)

PS: the entire patch of jquery UI:

```
function isLocal( anchor ) {
        return anchor.hash.length > 1 && 
                decodeURIComponent( unescape( unescape( anchor.href.replace( rhash, "" ) ) ) ) ===
                        decodeURIComponent( unescape( unescape( location.href.replace( rhash, "" ) ) ) );
}
```

Answer (score 17):

This is a consequence of the decodeURIComponent method, which assumes that the given string's percent encoded bytes are in UTF-8 (see step 4.d.vii.8 of the [Decode operation](http://es5.github.io/x15.1.html#Decode) in sec. 15.1.3 of ECMAScript). Your example string:

```
"file:///C:/Work/my%20project/yadda%20ac%E7%F5es%20yadda/submenu.html#tabs-1"
```

Contains the percent-decoded bytes 0xE7 0xF5, which can't occur one after the other in a valid UTF-8 string (they represent the two characters `çõ` in Windows-1252). Accordingly, decodeURIComponent throws a URIError exception.

One way to solve this, which I haven't tested yet, is to ensure that your Web page is served using the UTF-8 character encoding, rather than `ISO-8859-1`, which I presume is the default.

To do this, include a META tag as follows:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
```

(While the ideal thing is to include a Content-Type header containing the charset, this is not generally possible in local testing involving the file system.)

And also ensure that the Web pages themselves are encoded in UTF-8.

---

Also, where does your example string appear on your Web pages? How is it generated? What browser did you test the behavior on? The answer will help me tell you what to do.

Comment: changing encoding of your page to UTF-8 is not always feasible!

Answer (score 4):

Something like this ?

```
s = "file:///C:/Work/my%20project/yadda%20ac%E7%F5es%20yadda/submenu.html#tabs-1";
decodeURIComponent( unescape(s) )
```

Comment: Well... `unescape` is [being frowned upon](http://unspecified.wordpress.com/2008/05/24/uri-encoding/), so it will not probably be  clean solution. The proper question is: why `decodeURIComponent` fails on non-UTF8 URIs? Are these character encodings allowed in URIs or not? [RFC3986](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986) This non-UTF-8 URI was created by my browser (Firefox) by submitting a form on non UTF-8 page. So there must be a bug somewhere on the way in some of the standard software!

Comment: I investigated this issue a bit and it leads to different question - **[how these non UTF-8 characters got to the URIs and should they be there or not?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19702662/684229)**. Please see the included testcase.

Comment: Looks like the other thread/question got it solved?

It seems like the problem is in form encoding which is ISO but it should be utf8.

I did a quick google and found this conversion function which seems to work nicely with your form sample.

http://pastebin.com/cXqQpGwL

Comment: Thanks, interesting. Why they didn't use `accept-charset="utf-8"` attribute of the form element? It seems to do the same job, doesn't it?

Comment: I guess the function can be used outside of forms as well, e.g in ajax requests, or manually converting an url, before setting window.location.href

Comment: I finally patched my jqueryui and used your solution as a workaround, but I had to use it twice because I have some URI parameters which contain encoded URIS. So my solution was `decodeURIComponent( unescape( unescape(s)) )`. More generally, yhere should probably be `repeat-until` loop, unescaping until you keep getting the same result. This is workaround is not a clean solution apparently. [The clean solution is asked here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19702662/684229).

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error "Uncaught URIError: URI malformed" and I fixed it by doing :

`decodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(mystring))`

NB : changing encoding of my page to UTF-8 or adding unescape() were not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem myself. I couldn't find a way to clean my source string, so I just bypassed the exception, so the data would continue to load.
Hope this helps.

```
try {
    myVal = decodeURIComponent(sourceVal);
} catch (err) {
    myVal = "";
}
```

Comment: this is not a solution @Aryeh

Answer (score -3):

I cut and pasted the demo code into notepad saved in a folder path that had a space in the folder name (new folder) as test1.html.  Then I double clicked test1.html and it worked like a dream.

You obviously changed something and what ever it was change it back it will work fine.

Comment: Danny, it is not very clear what you speak about. Please clarify your answer - which demo you mean. Maybe it works fine because you changed the encoding of the file? It would be nice to describe what your change was.

Comment: @Tomas the very first link.  You know where it says "Demo Code".  I'm just saying if you can't duplicate the error you can't fix it.

Comment: you missed the point - you must have non UTF-8 chars in URI so saving as test1.html obviously can't work. You should follow the *whole* procedure to reproduce it. You can also follow my testcase here http://stackoverflow.com/q/19702662/684229.

Comment: @Tomas I just now tried naming the folder file:///C:/Users/daniel/Documents/ac%C3%A7%C3%B5es/test1.html#tab-1 it still works for me.  Crazy but when you paste the link into this crazy text box it escapes it and firefox put's it back.  I just can't duplicate the error so I can't step through the code and fix it.