# Uncaught URIError: URI malformed error with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, encryption

I'm using [node forge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-forge#aes) to encrypt a form before sending it to the server using [AES](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-forge#aes).

The code for the crypto part for now is

```
const bigInt = require("big-integer");
const forge = require('node-forge');

function generateParams() {
    // Cryptographic random number generator
    var array = new Uint32Array(2);
    var _key = bigInt(window.crypto.getRandomValues(array)[0]).toString();
    var _iv = bigInt(window.crypto.getRandomValues(array)[1]).toString();
    // generate random key and IV 
    var key = forge.util.encode64(_key);
    var iv = forge.util.encode64(_iv);
    const params = {
        key: key,
        iv: iv
    }
    return params;
}

function encrypt(params) {
    var cipher = forge.rc2.createEncryptionCipher(params.key);
    cipher.start(params.iv);
    // Encrypting "testing"
    cipher.update(forge.util.createBuffer("testing"));
    cipher.finish();
    return cipher.output;
}

function decrypt(params, encrypted) {
    var cipher = forge.rc2.createDecryptionCipher(params.key);
    cipher.start(params.iv);
    cipher.update(encrypted);
    cipher.finish();
    return cipher.output;
}
```

and the jQuery function is (not posting yet)

```
$('#recordForm').submit(function(event) {
    // Stop form from submitting normally
    event.preventDefault();
    // Grab form data
    // Crypto
    const params = generateParams();
    const encryptedForm = {
        test: encrypt(params),
    }
    console.log("Encrypted: " + encryptedForm.test);
    const decryptedForm = {
        test: decrypt(params, encryptedForm.id).data,
    }
    console.log("Decrypted: " + decryptedForm.test);
});
```

My problem is that I keep getting back (cryptob.js is the name of my file, generated with browserify)

```
Uncaught URIError: URI malformed
    at decodeURIComponent (<anonymous>)
    at Object.util.decodeUtf8 (cryptob.js:24437)
    at ByteStringBuffer.util.ByteStringBuffer.toString (cryptob.js:23490)
    at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (cryptob.js:1282)
    at HTMLFormElement.dispatch (jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js:3)
    at HTMLFormElement.q.handle (jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js:3)
```

when calling `encrypt()`.

There is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15326777/uncaught-urierror-uri-malformed-jquery-ui-tabs-on-windows#16639042) answer here which recommends including a special meta tag. I have done that but it still doesn't work. Since some resources online say it is related to UTF-8 encoding, I tried replacing

```
cipher.update(forge.util.createBuffer("testing"));
```

with

```
cipher.update(forge.util.createBuffer(encodeURIComponent("testing")));
```

or

```
cipher.update(forge.util.createBuffer("testing", 'utf8'));
```

but it didn't work either (based on [encodeURIComponent(str)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)).

You can test forge [here](https://npm.runkit.com/node-forge#aes), and if you run this code (which is essentially what I'm doing)

```
var forge = require("node-forge")

// generate a random key and IV 
var key = forge.util.encode64("12354523465");
var iv = forge.util.encode64("2315");

// encrypt some bytes 
var cipher = forge.rc2.createEncryptionCipher(key);
cipher.start(iv);
cipher.update(forge.util.createBuffer("testing"));
cipher.finish();
var encrypted = cipher.output; 
console.log(encrypted);

// decrypt some bytes 
var cipher = forge.rc2.createDecryptionCipher(key);
cipher.start(iv);
cipher.update(encrypted);
cipher.finish();
console.log(cipher.output.data)
```

it works fine.

How can I solve this?

Comment: RC2 is a different cipher than AES. Accoding to the documentation, either use `var cipher = forge.cipher.createCipher('AES-CBC', key);` or `forge.aes.createEncryptionCipher(key);`. Also, you shouldn't use CBC mode. It is better to use GCM mode.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this error is actually happening in the toString, where you generate your _key and _iv.

Try testing with some hard-coded strings, as used in the example code you posted. Then, use a method to generate random byte strings for the key and IV.

Also, for AES-256, the key should have 32 bytes (not bits) of entropy. The IV should have 16 bytes of entropy.